# Origin of German phrase "In der Ruhe liegt die Kraft."

Tags: etymology, phrase

I'm looking for the origin of this phrase, if it has one:

> "In der Ruhe liegt die Kraft."

Comment: It's *In der Ruhe liegt **die** Kraft.* I edited it.

Comment: The source is unknown. Some attribute it to Konfuzius which means it's really unknown.

Comment: Thank you, that is unfortunate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The origin seems to be unknown:

https://www.zeit.de/2011/47/Sprichwoerter/seite-9

"Erhaben wie eine moosbewachsene Buddhastatue thront diese Sentenz im Garten der Sprichwörter. Sogar die Wissenschaft hat sie zum Verstummen gebracht: Zu ihrer Entstehungsgeschichte schweigt die Parömiologie, die Lehre von den Sprichwörtern, sich schlichtweg aus. Still lächelnd und ungestört von jeglicher Hektik, nimmt sich diese Weisheitsformel das Recht, das Geheimnis ihrer eigenen Herkunft für sich zu behalten. Sie kann es sich leisten."

https://www.redensarten-index.de/suche.php?suchbegriff=~~In der Ruhe liegt die Kraft

"Interessant ist in diesem Zusammenhang, dass als Ursprung oft fernöstliche Philosophien - Konfuzius etwa - genannt werden. Dafür gibt es aber keinen Beleg. Es könnte sich daher um eine typische Projektion handeln: Im (Selbst-) Bild ist der Deutsche rational, fleißig und effektiv, und so wird die "andere Seite" fremden Kulturen zugeschrieben (einen ähnlichen Vorgang finden wir im Sprichwort "Der Weg ist das Ziel"). Wegen der Allgemeinheit der Aussage dürften sich in jedem Kulturkreis passende Passagen finden lassen, so auch in unserem: In der Bibel etwa heißt es in Jesaja 30,15: "Denn so spricht der Herr, HERR, der Heilige in Israel: Wenn ihr umkehrtet und stillebliebet, so würde euch geholfen; durch Stillesein und Hoffen würdet ihr stark sein" - und auch die Sprichwörter "Gut Ding will Weile haben" und "Ruh' erhält bei Kräften, macht hurtig zu Geschäften" gehen in diese Richtung.

Das Sprichwort wurde in den 1970er Jahren geläufig."

Comment: Die da übergesetzte Hebräische Form ist *be-shu-at wa-[*noakh*](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D7%A0%D6%BE%D7%95%D6%BE%D7%97) ([ref](https://biblehub.com/isaiah/30-15.htm)); Vgl auch *Shabbat* "Ruhe, Ruhetag", eventuel auch *Chanuka* (viz *Stille Nacht, heilige Nacht*).